# WPF - Catch a CLR event in A Style template

Tags: wpf, events, templates, styles

I have a style for a `ListBox`.  In the `ListBox` style I have a style for the ListBoxItems.  All of this is in the  section.

I want to catch the `IsEnabledChanged` event for the Listbox Items (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889108/wpf-datatrigger-setting-listboxitem-isselected) for why).  I tried setting up an `EventSetter`, but it can't see the event because it is not a "routed event".

How can I attach an event to this templated item?  (Remember it is not attached to a specific `ListBox` per-se.  It is a style in

Here is some sample code to show what I am talking about.

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="IsEnabledChanged" Handler="OnEnabledChanged"\>
            ....                     ^ 
                                     |
            This is not allowed ------
```

It can't find this event.  Trying to get more specific `ListBoxItem.IsEnabledChanged` does not help.

Edit:
I am not set on doing this in the XAML.  If there is some other way to do this via the code behind that would be just as good.  I just don't know how to get access to the resources templates from code behind.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem trying to move the code shown in the DataGrid of the WPFToolkit Tips & Tricks page to work within a style defined in a Resource Dictionary. 

http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing&referringTitle=Tips%20%26%20Tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately an EventTrigger will only work on RoutedEvents ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx)), it is not possible to use a CLR event in this case.

From the article:

> ...while EventTrigger objects start a set
>   of Actions when a specified routed
>   event occurs.

Comment: Is there some other way to get that event for my templated item?