# WPF ListView Row background color

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I am working with MVVM and WPF.

VM contains -

1. an Observable collection of Task (where Task is a class that has public properties TaskId, TaskTime and TaskDetails)
2. CurrentTaskId

I can set background color of each rows by using one of the method below

1. using ListView ItemContainerStyle Trigger  OR
2. using ListView ItemContainerStyleSelector

Now I want to set the background color of all the rows to LightBlue and the condition being Task.TaskId == VM.CurrentTaskId. How do I achive this?

I failed to implement it using the data trigger on the style because

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskId}" Value="1001">
```

is valid but using Binding for Value is not valid, something on the lines of

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskId}" Value="{Binding CurrentTaskId}">
```

I am able to implement the alternate row color and a specific color for certain rows using the StyleSelector but again how do I find the CurrentTaskId?

Also how would I implement the functionality to change background color everytime the CurrentTaskId changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using `IMultiValueConverter` and `MultiBinding`

Answer (score 1):

You should try using multi-binding in your data trigger.

See this question for a similar solution - [WPF DataTrigger - Setting ListBoxItem IsSelected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889108/wpf-datatrigger-setting-listboxitem-isselected)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I solved it. See my answer above. Thanks for the link +1