# WPF ListBox Item collapse datatrigger not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, listboxitem

I have a listbox and all I want to do is collapse the listboxitem based on a boolean property of my SelectedItem.
The IsVisible property on my client Model implements the NotifyPropertyChanged event.

Overview - I have a list of clients which users can do CRUDs on. When they delete, I set a boolean property on the Model which my VM exposes to the View. This should then only hide the 'deleted' row from the list. During a flush to db I CRUD based on the mode of the model.

```
<ListBox Name="listClients"
                 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                 Margin="0" BorderThickness="0"                     
                 Height="auto"
                 Style="{StaticResource BumListBox}"
                 SelectionMode="Extended"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClientList}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" >

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ClientNo}" Foreground="White" FontSize="{StaticResource HeaderFontSize}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ClientDesc}" Foreground="White" FontSize="{StaticResource SubHeaderFontSize}" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" />                           
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Code behind to jippo MVVM process:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_cvm.SelectedClient != null)
    {
        _cvm.SelectedClient.IsVisible = !_cvm.SelectedClient.IsVisible;
        _cvm.CurrentSelectedIsVisible = _cvm.SelectedClient.IsVisible;  //<- another       option to bind to
    }
}
```

I've tried the these suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697380/wpf-hiding-listbox-items) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889108/wpf-datatrigger-setting-listboxitem-isselected) or something similar but I just can't get to hide the items.

Any help in the right direction would be great, cheers.

**Edit**

I've tried Blam's suggestion below like this but still unable to hide the items:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: We don't generally handle `Click` events when using MVVM, preferring to use `ICommand`s in the view model instead. We also don't hide UI elements when they are deleted, instead removing them from the collections in the view model.

Comment: I agree, that's why I mention the Click event is a jippo to simulate the Command being called in my VM. Purely for tesing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was rather frustrating and the solution so simple. My client model with IsVisible is in a dll and the NotifyPropertyChanged() changes were never built to update the reference in my project..so the binding never happened. These late nights are taking their toll.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a converter if you are returning true/false but there is a system converter for that

Move it up to Resources
I have know I have used it this way

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Text">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=Vis}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Blam, thanks for that but I'm still unable to hide/collapse the item. I've edited my question to show what I did.

Comment: Don't know what to say. This works for me.  Try a hard coded Collapsed - it may be a binding or converter problem.